# Animated transform only for parent

Tags: html, css, transform, css-transforms

Is there any way to set transform for parent element, but not for child element? I tried set reverse values of transform to child element. It's working, but nested animation doesn't run linearly, even if there is `transition: all 1s linear;`. Here is [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ubw34Lj8/).

```css
.container, .title {
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.image {
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg);
  height: 300px;
  width: 800px;
}

.container {
  transform: scale(0.1); // 0.1× size of parent
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  transform: scale(10); // 10× size of child
}

.container:hover {
  transform: scale(0.5); // 0.5× size of parent on hover
}

.container:hover .title {
  transform: scale(2); // 2× size of child on hover
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="image">
   
   </div>
   <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think so. I this the effect you're going for? https://jsfiddle.net/ubw34Lj8/1/

Comment: **No, there isn't.** The only option is to transform the children back the other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since transform scale is multiplicative, 2 transform scales do not compensate during the transition.

Another transform that looks like scale, and that **is** linear is translateZ, when there is a perspective applied. Move the object 9 times the perspective, and the apparent size will be 1/10th.

See you snippet, with 2 opposite translateZ applied:

```css
body {
    perspective: 100px;
}
.container, .title {
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
.image {
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg);
  height: 300px;
  width: 800px;
}
.container {
  transform: translateZ(-900px);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.container:hover {
  transform: translateZ(-100px); 
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  transform: translateZ(900px); 
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.container:hover .title {
  transform: translateZ(100px); 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="image"></div>
   <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
</div>
```